# Works of Nassim Taleb

Tags: risk-management, soft-question

I am looking to find the list of math/statistics papers of Nassim Taleb. However the google scholar page only seems to show popular articles. I know that he's famous for his theory of randomness and antifragility and so on. I'm looking for a mathematically rigorous discussion of his ideas. Where can I can get his core academic papers. Or has he even done such work??

Comment: If the answers fulfilled the question, mark the answer please.

Answer (score 5):

On the N. N. Taleb's [website](http://www.fooledbyrandomness.com/CV.htm), you can find all his papers collected in the bibliography he updates on his own site.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

Go check out http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/cf_dev/AbsByAuth.cfm?per_id=475810

For social science literature, ssrn is almost always the best source.

Answer (score 1):

The papers mentioned in [Taleb's CV](https://www.fooledbyrandomness.com/CV.htm) are not linked to actual *PDF* files.

To get them, an advanced search on [Fooled By Randomness](https://www.fooledbyrandomness.com/) website will do the job,

> [site:fooledbyrandomness.com filetype:pdf pdf](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNS_0zfhX706luX_f8icIxHpPXP7IA%3A1575160979226&ei=kwzjXcatDfLRgwei4ajADA&q=site%3Afooledbyrandomness.com%20filetype%3Apdf%20pdf&oq=site%3Afooledbyrandomness.com%20filetype%3Apdf%20pdf&gs_l=psy-ab.3...840.7370..7766...3.0..0.354.2429.19j0j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.Yg9IdNSp7I8&ved=0ahUKEwiGw4X1m5PmAhXy6OAKHaIwCsgQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)

The search can be refined for particular articles.